# Order of Edwards curve and its twist

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation, ed448

In Mike Hamburg's [Ed448-Goldilocks, a new elliptic curve](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/625.pdf#page=5) ([eprint 2015](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/625), [WECCS 2015](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/events/2015/06/workshop-elliptic-curve-cryptography-standards)) it is studied untwisted Edwards curves in the prime field $\mathbb F_p$
$$E_d:\,y^2+x^2\,=\,1+d\,x^2\,y^2$$
with large prime $p\equiv3\pmod 4$ and the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) $\displaystyle\left(\frac d p\right)=-1$.

The matching "twist" is
$$E'_d:\,y^2-x^2\,=\,1-d\,x^2\,y^2$$

Constant $d$ is chosen with minimal $|d|$ such that the curve's order $|E_d|$ is $4\cdot q$ with $q$ prime, the twist's order is $|E'_d|=4\cdot r$ with $r$ prime, and $q<p/4$.

The paper uses prime $p=4^{224}-2^{224}-1$ and gives $d=-39081$,
$q=2^{446}-\mathtt{8335dc163bb124b65129c96fde933d8d723a70aadc873d6d54a7bb0d_h}$,
$r=2^{446}+\mathtt{0335dc163bb124b65129c96fde933d8d723a70aadc873d6d54a7bb0d_h}$

It holds $|E_d|+|E'_d|=2\cdot p+2$. Update: initially my experiments¹ differed by two but Mike Hamburg kindly pointed my mistake: I did not count the two points at infinity for $E'_d$.

The question (now) boils down to: **Why $|E_d|+|E'_d|=2\cdot p+2$ ? And how do we find $d$ given $p$ ?**

If the later is by mere enumeration of $d\gets-j\cdot\displaystyle\left(\frac j p\right)$ for incremental $j>0$ and checking $q\gets|E_d|/4$ and $r\gets|E'_d|/4$ are prime, how are these computed²?

---

¹ With $p\gets4^i-2^i-1$ for $i\in\{4,5\}$, I get
$$\begin{array}{r|rrr}
i&p&d&q&r\\
\hline
4&239&19&59&61\\
5&991&-45&233&263
\end{array}$$

² This may be asking for [Schoof–Elkies–Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm) adapted to Edwards curves. Pointer to an implementation also welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your questions. There is a relation between the order of a curve and its twist, this makes their sum always equal to $2p+2$. I guess the order was computed through SEA on the Weierstrass version.

Comment: @Ruggero: my question now boils down to [A] asking proof/argument for $|E_d|+|E'_d|=2p+2$; [B] if there is a shortcut to screen out some $d$ that won't give prime $q$ or $r$; [C] exactly how we do SEA on Edwards curves (I vaguely guess we compute the order $|E'_d|/2$ of an associated Weierstrass curve but do not immediately get which, and have zero experience with SEA. The closest thing is [these hints](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57435101#57435101) which I did not yet apply).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the [B] and [C] parts of the question per the comments:

I'm not sure how exactly did Mike Hamburg find the curve, but from what I know it's usually easier to find the order of the matching Montgomery curve. Recall that Montgomery curves have the form $By^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 + x$. If $B$ is 1, then it fits into the generalized Weierstrass form, and most SEA algorithm implementations work with any curve in the generalized Weierstrass form. (If it's not 1 then you can easily map into a curve with $B = 1$, the same way that short Weierstrass curves can be mapped into $a = -3$)

So basically:

- Search for a Montgomery curve matching the criteria;
- Then convert it into Edwards form.

One optimization is to instruct SEA to quickly discard curves whose order it knows beforehand that have a small factor (other than 4 or 8), see the [`tors` parameter of the `ellsea` PARI/GP function](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Elliptic_curves.html#se:ellsea), for example.

The paper ["A note on high-security general-purpose elliptic curves"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/647.pdf) has a Magma implementation of the process (though IIRC it uses a slightly different approach). [RFC 7748](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748#appendix-A) has a Sage script that also searches for a Montgomery curve (though it will probably be much slower, since it doesn't seem to support that optimization).

Comment: This is correct.  I implemented the behavior of ellsea with a negative tors parameter, to mean that the computation should abort if either E **or its quadratic twist** has order divisible by small primes other than tors.  A derived patch was later merged into upstream PARI/GP by someone else (David Leon Gil maybe?).  This functionality was at some point exposed in SAGE as well, but I'm not sure if it currently is.  Then I wrote a script to loop through values of d, checking first that d is nonsquare and some similar residuosity checks to rule out other 2-torsion and 8-torsion points.

Answer (score 6):

Do your experiments count points at infinity?  When $d$ is a quadratic nonresidue over $\mathbb{F}$, the curve

$y^2 + x^2 = 1 + d x^2 y^2$

has no points at infinity over $\mathbb{F}$.  But if $-1$ is also a quadratic nonresidue, then the curve

$y^2 - x^2 = 1 - d x^2 y^2$

has two of them, roughly of the form $(\pm\sqrt{-1/d}, \infty)$.

Comment: Ah, that's precisely my mistake. I edited the question to remove my bogus point count, and the **which** (formula for $|E'_d|$) part. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answering on the subquestion:

> Why $|E_d|+|E'_d|=2\cdot p+2$ ?

It follows from the definition of quadratic twist. In fact, let's consider all possible $\tilde{x}$ coordinates for points, that is all the values in $\mathbb{F_p}$, and an elliptic curve $E$ with equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, then:

**Case $\tilde{x}^3+a\tilde{x}+b\neq0$**:

So either $\tilde{x}^3+a\tilde{x}+b$ is a square and thus its square root provides us two points belonging to $E$, namely $(\tilde{x},\pm\sqrt{\tilde{x}^3+a\tilde{x}+b})$ or it is not a square.
If it's not a square then it will be a square for the twist curve $E'$ of equation $y^2=x^3+d^2ax+d^3b$ with $d\neq0$ and non-square in $\mathbb{F}_p$, thus providing two points belonging to $E'$.

**Case $\tilde{x}^3+a\tilde{x}+b=0$**:

In this case the point lies on the $x$ axis and belongs both to $E$ and $E'$.

So, when you consider all possible $\tilde{x}$ values in $\mathbb{F}_p$, you have for each of them two points belonging to $\{E \cup E'\}$, if you add also the point at infinity for each curve, you end up with $|E_d|+|E'_d|=2\cdot p+2$