# Finding of trace of Edward curve and proper $d$

Tags: elliptic-curves

The obvious way for computing the trace of curve is counting the number of curve point and then compute the trace of the curve by $t=p+1-\#E$. Are there any faster way for computing the trace of the curve? The above way is very slow. This question is also following up the [Finding of proper $d$ for Edward curve](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/91773/finding-of-proper-d-for-edward-curve). I hadn't been receive the proper response for it.

Comment: So, they are equivalent problems.

Comment: You are probably looking for Schoof's algorithm (and its improved variant, the SEA algorithm due to Schoof, Elkies, and Atkin).

Comment: Are there any code of generating of elliptic curve in GitHup or other sites?